# How to end a specific thread which was initialized by _beginthreadex

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, createthread, beginthreadex

i want to Close the thread which was initialized by the _beginthreadex. as i am also using Qt for GUI so when i use _endthreadex() then it Closes all threads which are running but i only want to Close or Exit the thread which was began by the _beginthreadex().

Comment: I have always simple returned and integer for my thread functions executed using _beginthreadex(). _endthreadex() is called automatically, when threads return.

Comment: Sorry, you should make sure it is the thread that's is executing _endthreadex() and not your main thread. If it is the latter, then everything exists

Comment: Threads must exit themselves, you cannot (safely) force another thread to close.  You need to arrange a way to tell the thread when it is time for it to exit.  Available mechanisms vary depending on what exactly the thread is doing.

Comment: actually the Problem is Qt will run always in a separate thread but i only want to Exit a specific thread...but _endthreadex() Closes all threads including GUI